# Convert generic method as async

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I have following generic method in abstract class which is in many places across application:

```
protected T Execute<T>(Func<T> func)
 {
            try
            {
                return func();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException invalidEx)
            {
                throw new InvalidException(invalidEx.Message, invalidEx);
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlEx)
            {
                throw new DbException(sqlEx.Message, sqlEx, ConvertSQLError(sqlEx));
            }
 }
```

It is in a base class and all derived classes use this one above in order to execute delegate Func. Calling code looks something like this:

```
public int SomeMethodInDerivedClass(.....){
    result = Execute(() =>
    {....code ommited becouse of clarity })
  }
```

What would be the best way to

1. Rewrite this method to be able to call it in an async way
2. Use await efficiently in calling code?

What I would like to achieve, actualy to be able to rewrite SomeMethodInDerivedClass so that it can return Task instead of int? Where should I start from?

Thank you in advance

Comment: it's just adding `async` to your signature and `await` in calling code (assuming the calling code is `async` itself).

Comment: You'll probably also have to change `Func<T>` to `Func<Task<T>>`, so that you can call `return await func();`.

Comment: Is your question about allowing your method to accept seamlessly BOTH a non-async AND an async func?

Comment: @FstTesla My question is to be able to inside of delegate I am passiing into base class be able to do something like this connection.OpenAsync() instead of connection.Open()

Answer (score 2):

I think you can add another method for your async Func:

```
protected async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
{
    try
    {
        return await func();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

If you want rethrow an exception, use previous code instead of create another exception because you lose the original exception context when you create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

`async` `await` is like zombie curse, it will contaminate entire codebase. It's not that bad however.
Yes, to use efficiently `async` `await`, you need to return `Task<T>`. So in your example would be `Task<int>`.
However is the delegate an asynchronous operation? If not you need to make it behave as one, so you need to wrap it into a Task.

It's quiet difficult to give you exact steps, as like I said, it should contaminate up to main, so everything operate on `async` `await` and `Task`, for the code to really benefit from the pattern.

Comment: Thank you, the case is that in particular cases I need delegate as asynchronous operation. It depends from case to case, but I think this might be an answer;

Comment: you mean, to treat the delegate as asynchronous operation? If yes, then the answer is there, you need to wrap the delegate in a new Task and await it.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I acome up with following solution:

```
 protected async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        try
        {
            return await Task.Run(func);
        }
```

And calling code is like this one:

```
public async Task<int> SomeMethod(......)
    {
                    
            result += await ExecuteAsync(() =>
            {
            ....code ommited for brevity 
            }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe better using Func<Task<T>>? In that form, you ensure that your function allow async/await

Comment: @Victor Thank you but that will not always be the case

Comment: Your solution violates [the guideline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) about not exposing asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods.